# How to deal with zip files in the wolfram cloud?

Tags: files-and-directories, wolfram-cloud, compression

I have a zip file in the cloud but I can't seem to unzip it!

```
a = CreateArchive[FindFile["ExampleData/rose.gif"], 
   OverwriteTarget -> True];    
c = CloudPut[a, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

I've tried things like this:

```
ExtractArchive[c, "/home/"]
```

What is the correct one-liner here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
a=CreateArchive[FindFile["ExampleData/rose.gif"],$TemporaryDirectory<>"test.zip"];
c=CopyFile[a,CloudObject[zipFile = "rose.zip",Permissions->"Public"],OverwriteTarget->True];
CloudEvaluate[ExtractArchive[zipFile,File["newRose"]]]
CloudEvaluate["LastModificationDate"/.FileInformation["newRose/rose.gif"]]
```

Comment: Ok, I forgot about `CloudEvaluate`, thanks!

Comment: @RolfMertig How does one share a downloadable zip file?

Answer (score 1):

`c = CloudPut[a, Permissions -> "Public"]` simply puts the file path(an expresstion) of the archived file and not the actual archived contents. So you need to use `CopyFile` for that.
So if your question is about first deploying the content to cloud from desktop Mathametica and archiving it below should work:

```
In[67]:= a = 
 CreateArchive[FindFile["ExampleData/rose.gif"], 
  OverwriteTarget -> True];

In[68]:=  CopyFile[a, CloudObject["archivedFileOnCloud"]]

Out[68]= CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/damanjits/\
archivedFileOnCloud"]

(* Also notice that you need to use $HomeDirectory to actually get the path of the
 archived file,  ExtractArchive currently does not work on CloudObject heads
like other file operations like FilePrint, CopyFile etc works *)

In[72]:= CloudEvaluate[
 ExtractArchive[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "archivedFileOnCloud"}]]]

Out[72]= {"/wolframcloud/userfiles/050/050bddf0-a081-42a3-88a4-\
576c739a59c2/rose.gif"}

In[78]:= CloudEvaluate[
  Import["/wolframcloud/userfiles/050/050bddf0-a081-42a3-88a4-\
576c739a59c2/rose.gif"]] // Head

Out[78]= Image
```

If you directly want to do archiving/unarchiving on cloud(I mean on cloud notebook) you can simply use:

```
In[11]:= file = CreateArchive[FindFile["ExampleData/rose.gif"], "archived.zip"];

In[12]:= Quiet@DeleteFile[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "rose.gif"}]]
Import[First@ExtractArchive[file]]//Head

Out[13]= Image
```